# Office365 API for GetUserAvailability

Tags: ios, outlook, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to find out how to call "GetUserAvailability" in office 365, either using the REST of existing API.  I know this API exists in exchange, but can't find it in Office 365.

If there is iOS implementation of this would be great as well.

Answer (score 2):

GetUserAvailability EWS SOAP API is available for Office 365 users.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuseravailability(v=exchg.80).aspx) for more info and let us know if you have questions.  We haven't yet released the same functionality in our [Office 365 Calendar REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations), but this is ranked high on our list of features to support.  When we add support to the REST APIs, you will be able to use the [iOS SDK for the REST APIs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS) to access the same.

Comment: Venkat, I have the same request - I'd like to use GetUserAvailability (or a similar function) using Office 365 rest apis with OAuth. The existing findMeetingTimes function doesn't work for my use case.

Is there another way to do this today? If not, are you still planning on supporting it? Thanks!